# Hystrix - How to calculate thread pool size

Tags: java, spring, performance, hystrix

Hystrix docs states that the thread pool size should be calculated as:

> requests per second at peak when healthy × 99th percentile latency in
>   seconds + some breathing room

For the following example we would have:

- Service with 50 rps when healthy
- 99th percentile latency: 0.5 seconds

Then 50 * 0.5 = 25 threads.

Now, as I understand 99th percentile latency, I think it means that 99% percent of the requests will take less than its value to answer.

If I want less latency, let's say 0.25 seconds:

50 * 0.25 = 12.5 threads.

This doesn't look right, as it seems to indicate that with less threads you get less latency. Could someone explain this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to change your point of view.

You cannot control the latency with Hystrix, you can only set the number of threads to avoid requests to be rejected.

So the latency is an independent variable, if you have a shorter latency you would need less thread to avoid rejections, which makes absolute sense.

[Here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#ThreadPool) the details.

Comment: @carlosmas I see your point, could you develop what the 99th latency is? I mean, is it the time you **expect** 99% of your requests to last, the time you have **measured** when healtly, or something else?

Comment: Yes, to me is the time that you expect for XY% (e.g. 99%) of request to last, when the system is healthy.
If the system is not healthy your latency could be infinite for each request (e.g. a link is broken and not even one request is fulfilled).